# Python3 - How to run Bash commands in multiple tabs of Ubuntu Terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, terminal

in my Ubuntu machine (version 20.04.2 MATE), I have some active services. every time I turn on the system, I want to see all its main info in the terminal and to make the reading easier, each output must be showed in a specific tab.

to do that, I created this python script:

```
import os

# commands with their tab names:
dic_cmds={"INFO":"ifconfig && netstat -nr", "XRDP":"systemctl status xrdp", "DHCP":"systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service"}

# run the commands in the terminal:
for key, value in dic_cmds.items():
    os.system(f"mate-terminal --tab --title=\"{key}\" -e \'bash -c \"{value} && sleep 5\"'")
```

it works, but I have some issues that I need to fix:

1. in each tabs opened, I can't see the prompt with the command sent, but I want to see it!
2. all the tabs should close themselves after 5 seconds, I specified it in the bash command but, what about if want to keep all of them "alive" without a sleep time? the "XRDP" and "DHCP" tabs stay "alive" only because their outputs ask for an input (to exit).
3. I can't interact with none of tabs opened. I just want to send the command, but after that, I want to use the terminal as a normal one, but the prompt doesn't exist!